# Python: Where To Find Import For Exception

Tags: python

How do you find where a custom Exception is defined so that you can import it.  In my stacktrace of an error that is thrown in my code I am getting a NoSuchElementException.  I would like to catch this specific exception but I can't find where to import it from.  Is there a way to determine what to import from the stacktrace?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/tablecloth/src/tablecloth/apps/atsa/adaptor.py", line 266, in login
    welcome_field = driver.find_element_by_class_name(self.welcome_id)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/tablecloth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 342, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/tablecloth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 680, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/tablecloth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/webapps/tablecloth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 158, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element: {"method":"class name","selector":"userName"}' ; Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_
```

Comment: Can you show what your code, and what you actually want to do? It's hard to understand the question.

Comment: I would look at where the function raising that exception got it.  In your case, `/home/ubuntu/webapps/tablecloth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Catch the exception with `Exception` so that you have access to the exception object:

```
try:
    call_your_function()
except Exception as e:
    print e.__module__
```

Then replace `Exception` with the more specific one you find out.